# Confused with Cucumber and seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I am trying to test the following:

-> As a User, I want to be able to create Posts.  Each Post has content and also a Category (which is another Model), that I should be able to select from a dropdown.

I have the following step:

```
When /^I create a post with valid data$/ do
  visit new_post_path
  # Here it would go the fill for content
  # Here it would go the select of category
end
```

My question is: Where should I define the categories? In a seed file or..?

Edit: My doubts are, that, for example in my (form) view I have:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.select "category_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name") %>
</div>
```

Once from my step definition I visit the "new" path, it will visit the view, but Category.all will return nothing. How do I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any background setup you want, i.e. things that your test relies on should be specified in the Given section.

```
Background:
  Given Categories exist
```

You can then specify in the steps what items you want to be available for the view.  e.g. `FactoryGirl.create(:category)` or whatever

When the Given is specified with Background it will run before every scenario in the file, great for setting up dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can seed the test database, or you can also use a gem like [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!sequences) with sequences, it would allow you to do generate unique values such as:

```
Fabricate.sequence(:category) { |i| "Category #{i}" }
# => "Category 0"
# => "Category 1"
# => "Category 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is, use a library that implements the [test data builder pattern](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) to create any data you need in a Given step. [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) and [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), as mentioned in the other answers, are probably the most commonly used test data builders but there are lots of others.